# Working with Pictogram Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I was playing around with the pictogram example (attached below). I want to add a y-axis to the diagram, but I keep running into an unexpected EOF error. Would appreciate any help.

Example: https://gist.github.com/alansmithy/d832fc03f6e6a91e99f4

Code Added:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("class","y label")
   .attr("text-anchor","end")
   .attr("y",6)
   .attr("dy",".75em")
   .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
   .text("Test y-label")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing *your* whole code, that is, *where* exactly you added your snippet, it's hard to reproduce your error.

But you just need a couple of changes for this to work: your selection is `svgDoc`, not `svg`. And set the `x` attribute, so you can move it down:

```
svgDoc.append("text")
    .attr("class", "ylabel")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", -20)
    .attr("y", 2)
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .text("Test y-label");
```

Here is the demo: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/08087207f684afbb414c7e61009f7f58/